# jquery smooth rotate on mousemove

Tags: jquery, transform

I would like to add some cool UI with rotating background on mouse move, like on icloud.com, for now I got the code below

```
        $("#VIEW").mousemove(function(e){
             var pageCoords = e.pageX + e.pageY;
             var max = $(document).width() + $(document).height();
                 var p = (pageCoords/max)*30;
             $('#ROTATE').css({ 'transform':'rotate(' + p + 'deg)'});
        });
```

problem is, this is realtime rotate, I like to make it slow, add some delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**animate()**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('#ROTATE').animate({ 'transform':'rotate(' + p + 'deg)'}, 600);
```

Comment: seems like does not work for me, not rotating at all, with no errors

Comment: anyway thanks for advice about animate, jQueryRotate.js +  $("#ROTATE").rotate({animateTo:p})
works for me.

Comment: @user840250 it could work for you if you add a prefix to the transform to make it cross browser, ex; -moz-transform, -webkit-transform, -o-transfrom and -ms-transform. you could also use jquery version prior to 1.7.2, it will add the prefixes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to read this http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples. You have many examples for rotate images.
For example :

```
$("#img").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        mouseover : function() { 
            $(this).rotate({animateTo:180})
        },
        mouseout : function() { 
            $(this).rotate({animateTo:0})
        }
     } 
});
```